# Keep track of pthread

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, posix

I put up many threads running. At a later time, I'd like to check if these threads are still alive (i.e., not finished yet and not terminated unexpectedly).

1. What kind of information should I keep track of regarding the threads in the first place. Thread ID, process ID, etc? How should I get these IDs?
2. When I need to check the liveness of these threads, what functions should I use? Will `pthread_kill` work here? `pthread_kill` takes an opaque type `pthread_t` as parameter, which I believe is typically an `unsigned long`. Is `pthread_t` different from a thread ID? I assume a thread ID would pick up an int as its value. In some tutorials on pthread, they assign an integer to a pthread as its ID. Shouldn't the thread get its ID from the operating system?

Comment: @Duck I believe I have to take both into account.

Comment: pthread_t is a typedef meaning that it can be a lot of things, not just a long.  Yes, pthread_create returns a threadid as a pthread_t datatype.  Use an array of pthread_t to store active threadids.

Comment: @jimmcnamara what could be the size of type pthread_t since I need to store these IDs in shared memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A thread's entire identity resides in `pthread_t`
2. Initializing a thread returns its `pthread_t` typed ID to its parent
3. Each thread can get it's own ID with `pthread_self()`
4. You can compare thread IDs using the function:`int pthread_equal (pthread_t, pthread_t)`

So: Maintain a common data structure where you can store thread status as STARTED, RUNNING, FINISHED using the `pthread_t` IDs and `pthread_equal` comparison function to differentiate between the threads. The parent sets the value to STARTED when it starts the thread, the thread itself sets its own state to RUNNING, does its work, and sets itself to FINISHED when done. Use a mutex to make sure values are not changed while being read.

EDIT:
You can set up a sort of 'thread destructor' using `pthread_cleanup_push`:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cleanup_pop.html

i.e. register a routine to be called when the thread exits (either itself, or by cancellation externally). This routine can update the status.

Comment: When a thread is terminated unexpectedly, what would the status of that thread be? In other words, when the thread no longer exists, how should we make sure it's gone?

Comment: AFAIK, calling pthread_kill with SIG set to 0 checks if the thread is valid. I am not sure if terminated threads that were once running are considered valid. If they are not, this is a good condition to use.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: You might be able to make use of pthread cancellation cleanup handlers using `pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop`. These are called when the thread is cancelled, calles `pthread_exit`, or calls the matching `pthread_cleanup_pop` with a non-zero argument.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you call `pthread_create`, the first argument is a pointer to a `pthread_t`, to which `pthread_create` will assign the thread ID of the newly created thread. If you want to get the thread ID of the current thread, use `pthread_self()`. This is the only identifying piece of information you need for the thread because all threads created this way share the same process ID.
2. The way you would check whether a thread is alive depends on what you need this information for. If you just want to wait until the thread has completed, you call `pthread_join` with the thread ID as the first argument and a pointer to a location for the return value of the thread function as the second argument. Unless you detach the threads you create by calling `pthread_detach(pthread_self())` in the thread, you need to call `pthread_join` on them eventually so that they don't continue to hold on to their stack space.

   If for some reason you want to do something while the thread is running, you could create a global variable for each thread that that thread changes when it terminates, and check that variable with the main thread. In that case, you would probably want to detach the threads so that you don't also have to join them later.